# "Batch" renaming one file at a time in Python

Tags: python, list

I would like to perform a sort of "manual" batch operation where Python looks in a directory, sees a list of files, then automatically displays them one at a time and waits for user input before moving on to the next file.  I am going to assume the files have relatively random names (and the order in which Python chooses to display them doesn't really matter).

So, I might have `pic001.jpg` and `myCalendar.docx`.  Is there a way to have Python move through these (in any order) so that I can prepend something to each one manually?  For instance, it could look like

```
Please type a prefix for each of the following:


myCalendar.docx:
```

and when I typed "2014" the file would become `2014_myCalendar.docx`.  Python would then go on to say

```
Please type a prefix for each of the following:


myCalendar.docx: 2014
... myCalendar.docx renamed to 2014_myCalendar.docx

pic001.jpg:
```

then I could make it `disneyland_pic001.jpg`.

I know how to rename files, navigate directories, etc.  I'm just not sure how to get Python to cycle through every file in a certain directory, one at a time, and let me modify each one.  I think this would be really easy to do with a for loop if each of the files was numbered, but for what I'm trying to do, I can't assume that they will be.

Thank you in advance.

Additionally, if you could point me to some tutorials or documentation that might help me with this, I'd appreciate that as well.  I've got http://docs.python.org open in a few tabs, but as someone who's relatively new to Python, and programming in general, I find their language to be a little over my head sometimes.

Comment: [`os.walk`](http://devdocs.io/python/library/os#os.walk)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
DIR = '/Volumes/foobar'

prefix = raw_input('Please type a prefix for each of the following: ')

for f in os.listdir(DIR):
    path = os.path.join(DIR, f)
    new_path = os.path.join(DIR, '%s%s' % (prefix, f))
    try:
        os.rename(path, new_path)
        print 'renamed', f
    except:
        raise
```